How to Calculate the Number of Pairs in a Tree Based on Maximum Edge Weight?
I am working with a weighted tree and need to answer multiple queries efficiently. Each query asks for the number of pairs of vertices (u,v) such that the maximum edge weight on a simple path between u and v does not exceed a given value .The output should be the results of all queries in order.
Definitions:
Tree:

A connected graph with n vertices and no cycles.
Consists n - 1 edges.
Each edge has a weight  and connects two vertices ui and vi.

Simple path:

A path between two vertices that does not revisit any vertex.​

Query

Given an integer qi, determine the number of pairs (u,v) where u < v uch that the maximum edge weight on a simple path between u and v is ≤ qi.


Input:
1.The first line contains two integers n,m where n is the number of vertices and m is the number of queries (1≤n,m≤200,000).
2.The next n-1 lines each describe an edge in the tree with three integers wi,ui,vi

w: weight of the edge (1≤≤200,000).
ui,vi: vertices connected by the edge(1≤ui,vi≤n).

3.The final line contains m integers q1,q2,…,qm where qi is the maximum weight or the -th query (1≤q≤200,000).

Output:
A single line containing  integers. Each integer corresponds to the result of the -th query:

The number of vertex pairs (,) where < and the maximum edge weight on the simple path between them is ≤.


Example:
input:
7 5
1 2 1
3 2 3
2 4 1
4 5 2
5 7 4
3 6 2
5 2 3 4 1
output:
21 7 15 21 3
Input:
1 2
1 2
Output:
0 0
Input:
3 3
1 2 1
2 3 2
1 3 2
Output:
1 3 3

My attempt:
I tried implementing a solution using union-find (disjoint set union) with edge sorting and query processing. The general approach is:

Sort the edges by weight.

Sort the queries by .

Use union-find to incrementally connect nodes by edge weights up to .

Count the pairs using the sizes of connected components.



Here is my Python code which fails for test cases in my university platform:
from collections import defaultdict

class UnionFind:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.parent = list(range(size))
        self.size = [1] * size

    def find(self, x):
        if self.parent[x] != x:
            self.parent[x] = self.find(self.parent[x])  
        return self.parent[x]

    def union(self, x, y):
        root_x = self.find(x)
        root_y = self.find(y)
        if root_x != root_y:
            if self.size[root_x] < self.size[root_y]:
                root_x, root_y = root_y, root_x
            self.parent[root_y] = root_x
            self.size[root_x] += self.size[root_y]
            return self.size[root_x] * self.size[root_y]
        return 0

def count_pairs(n, m, edges, queries):
    edges.sort()
    queries = [(q, i) for i, q in enumerate(queries)]
    queries.sort()
    
    uf = UnionFind(n + 1)
    results = [0] * m
    current_pairs = 0
    edge_index = 0
    

    for q, idx in queries:
        while edge_index < len(edges) and edges[edge_index][0] <= q:
            w, u, v = edges[edge_index]
            current_pairs += uf.union(u, v)
            edge_index += 1
        results[idx] = current_pairs
    
    return results

import sys
input = sys.stdin.read
data = input().splitlines()
n, m = map(int, data[0].split())
edges = [tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in data[1:n]]
queries = list(map(int, data[n].split()))

print(*count_pairs(n, m, edges, queries))


Would love to get any help and assistance.
Thanks!

The output in the 1st example seems to contradict the rules (3 vertex pairs with max_weight = 1, when only the 1-2 edge has a weight of 1...); are you sure the order is not ui, vi, wi ? I manually checked and this would fit too 7 when max_weight = 2.

I also notice that w is never used in your count_pairs function, so I can't see how it could help solve the problem.

Yes you are correct, the order is ui,vi,wi.
My mistake

Edit your question so that it is correct.  Do not hide corrections in comments.

Voting to close as the question has misleading information as pointed out above.

I think the problem is in the way you handle the result.

        self.size[root_x] += self.size[root_y]
        return self.size[root_x] * self.size[root_y]


I think what you want is the original size[root_x] * size[root_y], then sum up the sizes.
I'm not sure why you're not seeing this in the examples already. If you have 2 nodes linked by an edge, the original code would do 1+1 first then return 2*1 but the answer should be 1 (because the problem asks for unique pairs, u<v). If you first multiply, then update you are getting the correct answer 1 and still have the correct size=2 at the end.
When encountering problems, it's useful to create a handful of simple tests to verify your code. The ones in the problem statement could be handpicked to avoid highlighting interesting corner cases (but probably still useful as a check).
